# comparing innerText/textContent with a value inside a variable

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, nightmare

I am using Nightmare.js to webscrape and trying to add an id to a button with specific text so that I can click it since the page is dynamically generated with javascript. The code below doesn't work because for some reason I can't use a variable inside the indexOf in the if statement.

```js
const Nightmare = require('nightmare')
const nightmare = Nightmare({ show: false })
const rp = require('request-promise');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

var size = "9";

nightmare
  .goto('https://www.flightclub.com/')
  .type('#search', 'air jordan 4 cactus jack \u000d')
  .wait(1000)
  .click('.result-thumbnail')
  .evaluate(() => {
    var correctSize = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
    for (var i = 0; i < correctSize.length; i++) {
      if (correctSize[i].textContent.indexOf(size) > -1) correctSize[i].id = 'thisone';
    }
  })
  .click('button[id=thisone]')
  .end()
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Search failed:', error)
  })
```

However, it works if I change it to

```
if (correctSize[i].textContent.indexOf("9") > -1) correctSize[i].id ='thisone';
```

where the `"9"` replaces `size`. Is there a reason why I can't do an indexOf for a variable but can with a regular string of the same value? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable isn't what you've defined it in node's scope, as evaluate runs in the browser's scope. You need to pass the variable to evaluate like below

```
  .evaluate((____size) => {
    var correctSize = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
    for (var i = 0; i < correctSize.length; i++) {
      if (correctSize[i].textContent.indexOf(____size) > -1) correctSize[i].id = 'thisone';
    }
  }, (____size))
```

then it works

Assuming you named the variable ____size...